# How can I get DPI from image in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I work on a HTML5 canvas to calculate distance on image between two points. I want to convert this distance in pixel to cm. I found a formula : pixels * 2.54 / DPI. So, I would like to know if it's possible to get DPI image properties in JS? Or, can I use an easiest way to calculate cm from pixels?

Thank you.

Comment: DPI (Dots per Inch) is an information intended to be used by **printers**. You can't use it for digital media. There is no notion of metric distance there. Take for instance someone displaying your image on a phone and someone else using a beam projector.

Comment: DPI *is* relevant to screens, now that high-density screens exist, and I assume that's what they're asking about (it's more accurately referred to as PPI or pixel density but DPI is close enough)

Comment: @DanielBeck Nope, it's still irrelevant, high density or not, the DPI information you have in an EXIF metadata is simply ignored when displayed on a monitor. You are confusing the number of pixels there is in a raster image, and the number of physical pixels a monitor will use to display one `px` (the CSS unit), which is called DPR. These are not related, and you can't get what OP is willing to get (physical displayed dimensions). And note that difference of PPI existed since there have been at least two monitors manufactured.

Comment: @Kaiido They're using the wrong terminology, agreed.  But they're not asking about EXIF data, they're asking about the physical distance between pixels on a `canvas`. Which *can* be determined from the DPR.

Comment: @DanielBeck, Still not. Like I said in my first comment, you have no way to tell how far the wall on which my beam projector is displaying this image is, hence you can't tell how big the displayed image is. Same for any monitor, the PPI information is not available (I don't think the OS knows either), for instance if you take a LED matrix like there are on buildings, you may have a 1PPI monitor, and it may still display at 2DPR, simply because it's huge enough to use 4 pixels for one CSS `px`.

Comment: Goodness. Presumably if they were asking about unusual edge cases like beam projectors and LED matrixes they would have mentioned that in the question. Seems like much less of a stretch to imagine that they said "DPI" when they meant "PPI", personally, but I suppose if I'm wrong about that they'll be able to clarify...

Comment: @DanielBeck ...I'm using extreme examples to make it clear it can't be done. Now, you have to understand that even with non extreme cases it still can't be done. You may be lucky, and fall on a user that is using a 96PPI monitor (*was* the most common for desktop monitors), and which has no zoom neither at the browser level, nor at the OS level (which means they did change the default settings if on windows), then yes, you may find it. But once again, that would be just luck, and there are almost as much chances to get it all wrong.

Answer (score 12):

What you are asking for, to retrieve the physical displayed size in *cm* of anything digital, can't be done without a lot of heuristics, that is, **we as web-developer have no way to do it for all our visitors.**

---

### About Your formula:

#### DPI - [Dots Per Inch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dots_per_inch).

This is a measure of how many dots can fit in a single inch. This unit is usually for printers or scanners. A monitor however has no dots and thus *DPI* has no meaning for it.

Digital media like images may embed a *DPI* information in their metadata, but this is only a hint on either the settings the **scanner** used when generating the file, either a hint by the author for the intended size it should be **printed**.  Only a few dedicated softwares will make use of this information, and your web browser is not of them.

#### Digital Pixel - (raster Picture-Cell).

This is the smallest unit of visible information in a [raster graphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics). These information may be stored in many ways, but is not divisible by other means than creating new, fake data. That's generally the "*px*"  we refer to in *1920x1080px*.
To make it easier to understand, we can take the case of bitmaps, where each *digital pixel* is represented by its own set of bits in the file, to make it easier again, let's take the example of an 8bit bitmap image (single-color, generally gray-scale). Here 8 bits are used to represent a single digital pixel (a color dot). For instance we can make a 2x2px bitmap with these information:

```
[2, 125, 255, 125, 255]
 |   |    |    |    - pixel (2,2) 100% intensity
 |   |    |     - pixel (2,1) 50% intensity
 |   |     - pixel (1,2) 100% intensity
 |    - pixel (1,1) 50% intensity
  - width (nb of digital pixels per line)
/* height can be determined by the `length of data array / width` */
```

Beware though, all raster images are not bitmaps, and they don't all have this *bits-pixel* relation, but they do all have a concept of digital pixel, as in the smallest block of color information they do hold.

---

With these two concepts clarified, we can explain what your formula means:

```
const pxTocm = (pixels, DPI) => pixels * 2.54 / DPI;
```

If we take a 150*150px raster image, and print it using a quite good inkjet-printer with a 300DPI resolution, this formula will correctly give us 1.27cm, or 0.5in

**But this only works if we know the printed resolution**.

---

Alright, then let's just use the screen resolution.

#### PPI - Pixels Per Inch.

This is what we would need for most monitors. Very similar to DPI, this measures the number of **physical pixels** a monitor does contain in a single inch.
What a *physical pixel* for a monitor is vary with the type of monitor used, but for instance in most LCD monitors, one physical pixel is made of three diodes, one Red, one Green, and one Blue, also called sub-PIXELs.

[image: A photograph of sub-PIXEL display elements on a laptop's LCD screen]
<sub>You can see all three sub-Pixels components composing a single pixel.</sub>
<sub>*Image credits: CC-BY-SA 4.0 Krapteek88 for wikimedia.org*</sub>

So we could indeed rewrite your formula to be

```
const pxTocm(pixels, PPI) => pixels * 2.54 / PPI;
```

But that would work only if the image was displayed at 100%, that is one *digital pixel* takes up one *physical pixel*, which is rarely the case on the web, and moreover, **we would need to know this PPI value**.

From the Web APIs, we have **no way** of knowing that *PPI* value. We can't even be sure we are displaying to a monitor, it could very well be a beam projector, for which the concept of *PPI* has no meaning whatsoever.

The closest we have is the screen resolution (under `Window.screen` object, but this will only give us the number of *digital pixels* the display holds; we still miss the actual physical size of this display.

```
PPI = Math.hypot(screen.width, screen.height) / physical_size_of_diagonal
// and we don't have any way to find this diagonal...
```

---

**But what is `window.devicePixelRatio` I heard about if not my screen's *PPI*?**

To explain that, we first need to explain what is a *CSS `px`*

#### CSS `px` - Reads as "pixel" but is not a pixel.

A `px` is an unit, [called by W3C](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html) *"the magic unit of CSS"*. It value depends on the support, and its distance to the viewer's eyes (!). [Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#reference-pixel) you can find a quite accessible explanation of what is a *reference pixel* for CSS.
Basically, it should look the same size if you are viewing on a monitor at harm distances, and if you are looking on a phone at closer distance.

I hope you get how hard it is to map this to a real-life measurement.

#### `window.devicePixelRatio`

This value represents the number of physical pixels that will get used to display a `CSS px`.
This *could* have been useful, because with this value we can map precisely one css `px` to the number of physical pixels being used.

If we knew what a CSS `px` really represents i.e (are we on a monitor or a mobile device or some other device?), and what is the current PPI resolution of our user's monitor (but we don't), then we could have measured the displayed size on the monitor. (But we can't).

So yes, we can, on a 96PPI desktop monitor, with no OS zoom, get the kind or formula @JuMoGar provided in their answer (note though they got it wrong):

```
const CSSpxTocm = (CSSpx) => CSSpx * 2.54 / (96 / devicePixelRatio);
```

where `96` is the 96PPI hard-coded value CSS `px` unit uses in their 96th of an inch.

But simply try it on mobile phone, and you'll see how broken it is. [As a fiddle if it's easier from mobile.](https://jsfiddle.net/ycn321ef/embedded/result)

```js
const CSSpxTocm = (CSSpx) => CSSpx * 2.54 / (96 / devicePixelRatio);

console.log(CSSpxTocm(96) + 'cm');
```

```css
.test {
  border-top: 3px solid blue;
  height: 10px;
  width: 96px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test px"></div>
```

On my 125PPI laptop's monitor <sub>(13.3in 1280x1080px)</sub>, it is already wrong, stating that it is 2.54cm, while it is in fact around 2.2cm, but on my Galaxy S6 phone, [it returns 10.16cm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNFGu.jpg) while IRL, it is roughly 1.7cm.

Why? Because the screen has ~577 PPI, but still, it uses only one *physical pixel* per *CSS `px`*. This means the `devicePixelRatio` is still `1`, but the *PPI* being so far from expected 96, this formula returns absurdities. <sub>(The diagonal of an S6 screen is 5.1in, ~12.9cm)</sub>

Answer (score 3):

You can get the size of cms from an image using JavaScript. Take in care that DPI are different in each device so, I use `window.devicePixelRatio` to get DPI of the screen that shows the image (can be a NoteBook, Mobile, Tablet,...).

One way is:

```
/* Convert px to cm */
function getSizeInCM(sizeInPX) {
   return sizeInPX * 2.54 / (96 * window.devicePixelRatio)
};

/* get width and height of an image in cms */
var img = document.getElementById('IMAGE_ID'),
var width = getSizeInCM(img.clientWidth),
var height = getSizeInCM(img.clientHeight);
```

---

If you only want get the pixels of one image, it is simpler:

```
var imageWidth = document.getElementById("IMAGE_ID").width;
var imageHeigth = document.getElementById("IMAGE_ID").height;

// or...

var imageWidth = document.getElementById("IMAGE_ID").clientWidth;
var imageHeigth = document.getElementById("IMAGE_ID").clientHeight;
```

---

Another way to do that: You will need an extra library: [Blueimp's Load Image library](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image#user-content-meta-data-parsing) and use its `EXIF parsing extension`

Here is a code which returns its coordinates resolution:

```
loadImage.parseMetaData(FILE, function(meta) {
    if (!meta.exif) { return; }

    var resX = meta.exif.get('XResolution');
    var resY = meta.exif.get('YResolution');
});
```

Comment: I won't repeat how this is unreliable, already did in comments on the question, but I'll note it should be 96/DPR, not *.

Comment: brother return sizeInPX * 2.54 / (96 * window.devicePixelRatio) from where you get that 96 value ?

Answer (score 3):

[Sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) JavaScript library works well to get and set the resolution/density for the image files with [withMetadata](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/api-output#withmetadata) function.

Simple example:

```js
// get the metadata of an image 
sharp('input.jpg')
  .withMetadata()
  .toFile('output-with-metadata.jpg')
  .then(info => { ... });

// Set output metadata to 96 DPI
const data = await sharp(input)
  .withMetadata({ density: 96 })
  .toBuffer();
```

Npm module: [sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)